# Actualizar ASP: LABEL después de selección DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dropdownlist

Estoy realizando un trabajo de la facultad donde debo elegir un idioma de una lista desplegable *dropdownlist*. De acuerdo con el idioma seleccionado (español o ingles) hace una consulta a la base de datos y carga todas los IDs (NombreDelControl) con su valor (texto) en una lista.

```
Traducciones = IdiomaBLL.GetBLLServicioIdiomaUnico().TraduccionesSgl;
```

**Así declaro las label:** uso *ClientIdMode* para que permanezca estática mi *Id* y no genere una automática:

```
<asp:Label ID="IniciarSesion" ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server"  ></asp:Label>
```

Por otro lado tengo una función que recorre todos los controles y los carga en una Lista:

```
private void RecorrerControles(Control pObjetoContenedor)
{
    foreach (Control Controlobj in pObjetoContenedor.Controls)
    {
        ListaResultado.Add(Controlobj);

        if ((Controlobj) is System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)
        {
            RecorrerDropDown(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)Controlobj));
        }


        if (Controlobj.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            RecorrerControles(Controlobj);
        }

        ListaResultado.Add(Controlobj);
    }
}

private void RecorrerDropDown(System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList pMenuStrip)
{
    ListaResultado.Add(pMenuStrip);
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in pMenuStrip.Items)
    {
        ListaResultado.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Luego mapeo donde recorre por cada control (NombreDelControl) de la lista de control hasta que lo encuentra y machea con su valor (texto):

```
void IObservador.Traducirme()
{
    ListaResultado.Clear();
    RecorrerControles(this);

    Traducciones = IdiomaBLL.GetBLLServicioIdiomaUnico().TraduccionesSgl;

    try
    {
        foreach (Control Control in ListaResultado)
        {
            foreach (var traduccion in Traducciones)
            {
                if (Equals(Control.ID, traduccion.NombreDelControl))
                {
                    string tipo;
                    tipo = Control.GetType().ToString();
                    //ESTO SON LOS <a>
                    if (Control is Label lbltradu)
                    {
                        lbltradu.Text = traduccion.Texto;
                    }
                    //ESTOS SON LOS INPUT CON TYPE TEXT O PASSWORD
                    else if (Control is TextBox txttradu)
                    {
                        txttradu.Text = traduccion.Texto;
                    }
                    //ESTOS SON LOS <BUTTON>
                    else if (Control is IButtonControl ibtntradu)
                    {
                        ibtntradu.Text = traduccion.Texto;
                    }
                    //ESTOS SON LOS <INPUT> TYPE BUTTON O SUBMIT
                    else if (Control is LinkButton lbtntradu)
                    {
                        lbtntradu.Text = traduccion.Texto;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Sin embargo a pesar que trae la lista de traducciones correctamente, recorre todos los controles y trae sus id y luego aplica el mapeo , refresca la pantalla y persiste los texto en idioma español que es el que usa cuando se inicializa.

¿Me saben decir si debo agregar algo en el web config? o ¿Qué es lo que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Sí haces las consultas en base a una selección del dropdownlist ¿Dónde esta el evento **SelectedIndexChanged**? por otro lado cómo esta tu **Page_Load**??

Comment: Hola Jorge.. en el page_load de la masterpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ya lo solucione:** Por si a alguien le sirve , les comento que tenia armar un constructor cuando llamo a traducirme.

Por ejemplo:

```
public MasterPage()
{
    IObservable.AgregarObservador(this); 
}
```

En vez de ponerlo en el page_load.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Master Page. Elige Idioma y carga en español.

````
         {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ElegirIdioma();
                Traducciones = new List<MultiIdiomaEntidad>();
              
                IdiomaSeleccionado.IdIdioma = Int32.Parse(ddlidioma.SelectedValue);
               
                IdiomaBLL.GetBLLServicioIdiomaUnico().TraduccionesSgl = IdiomaBLL.GetBLLServicioIdiomaUnico().DevuelverTodosLosTextos(IdiomaSeleccionado.IdIdioma);
                Traducciones = IdiomaBLL.GetBLLServicioIdiomaUnico().TraduccionesSgl;
              IdiomaBLL.GetBLLServicioIdiomaUnico().Traducir(IdiomaSeleccionado.IdIdioma);

                IObservable.AgregarObservador(this); 
            }
            
        }

 public void ElegirIdioma()
        {

            ddlidioma.Items.Clear();
            ddlidioma.SelectedValue = null;
            idiomaEntidad = _IdiomaBLL.FindAll();
            ddlidioma.DataSource = idiomaEntidad;
            ddlidioma.DataValueField = "IdIdioma";
            ddlidioma.DataTextField = "Descripcion";
            ddlidioma.DataBind();

        }```
Despues cuando cambio de idioma pasa al
        protected void ddlidioma_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    ```    {

            IdiomaSeleccionado.IdIdioma = Int32.Parse(ddlidioma.SelectedValue);
          
            IdiomaBLL.GetBLLServicioIdiomaUnico().TraduccionesSgl = IdiomaBLL.GetBLLServicioIdiomaUnico().DevuelverTodosLosTextos(IdiomaSeleccionado.IdIdioma);
         
            IdiomaBLL.GetBLLServicioIdiomaUnico().Traducir(IdiomaSeleccionado.IdIdioma);


        }```
````